# How do you request xEGLD on testnet?

Tags: multiversx

The hidden faucet doesn't work on testnet. Apparently, the transaction is `Invalid`.

Example:

- URL: https://testnet-explorer.elrond.com/transactions/0cb0d14667d6cc76c753f5d31b888f3eaf75d7f4e41e222cac9ddbdbb45c5831
- Hash:
  `0cb0d14667d6cc76c753f5d31b888f3eaf75d7f4e41e222cac9ddbdbb45c5831`
- Status:
  `Invalid`

  [image: Transaction Details - Status: Invalid]

Any idea how to get some xEGLD on the testnet?

Comment: The testnet is reset once in a while, the link will stop working then.

Comment: Please use the devnet for testing adn development purposes. It's more stable and it has more developer tools (including the xEGLD Faucet).

Comment: @Mircea yes but sadly the functionality I needed was not available on the testnet at the time of this post. The devnet could not complie contracts using elrond-wasm 0.19.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 web interfaces to request xEGLD for non-production environments.

#### Testnet

1. https://r3d4.fr/elrond/testnet/index.php (3<sup>rd</sup> party)

   - max 5 / 24 hours
2. https://testnet-wallet.elrond.com/faucet (official)

   - max 10 / 24 hours
   - This calls the following endpoint `https://testnet-extras-api.elrond.com/faucet` under the hood.

P.S. During the competitions like Battle of Yields, the faucets can be temporarily disabled.

#### Devnet

1. https://r3d4.fr/elrond/devnet/index.php (3<sup>rd</sup> party)

   - max 5 / 24 hours
2. https://devnet-wallet.elrond.com/faucet (official)

   - max 10 / 24 hours
   - This calls the following endpoint `https://devnet-extras-api.elrond.com/faucet` under the hood.

---

P.S.: Meanwhile, I've sent 2 xEGLD to you:

https://testnet-explorer.elrond.com/transactions/19f091d012f8d3c74365b66b79950b6f946633622979cf587f792b994b778670

Comment: @Rob, did you read the question, and did you visit the URLs I provided?
They are web interfaces built to generate xEGLD, so some HTML forms, not web pages with code that can be copied here.

What you are saying is applicable in a different context, not here.

Comment: If you removed the links, is the question still solved and answered?

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. Thanks! Also thanks for the gift :)

Comment: @Rob, 
I am sure that if someone will search similar info in the future, (s)he wants to see those 2 links. The first one is official, the second one is maintained by a partner (3rd party). I'd say that the first one will never be removed. I'd make an analogy to a "download URL" or "API URL" from official websites. There are posts in StackOverflow where the URLs become deprecated after a while. Then someone adds a comment to emphasize the problem and they are usually updated. I will add some other details on the endpoints above to offer a better context.

Comment: @MerdescuR. , 
The 2nd option ( https://r3d4.fr/elrond/testnet/index.php ) works now. You can request 5 EGLD / day using it.

I tested it here:
https://testnet-explorer.elrond.com/transactions/dd139aa08a8b9452d2477efea8e650710b3459415d8ae0e4f50df7ba4717d7d9

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer thanks!